# create process error 2 android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

![enter image description here][1]I am runing a simple hello world application on android studio.but it is giving error ,create process error=2
I have defined the path and JAVA_HOME variables also but it still gives error.
My eclipse and previous android sdk is working properly.
Somebody help me to resolve this error.
thanks!

ERROR IS
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\Saifshine.AndroidStudioPreview\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Go to `File -> Project Structure -> SDKs` and select `1.6`. Then change the JDK home path option to match your installed JDK. This fixed the issue for me.